# An efficient way to find the most similar vectors

Tags: python

Let's say we train a model with more than 1 million words. In order to find the most similar words we need to calculate the distance between the embedding of the test word and embeddings of all the 1 million words words, and then find the nearest words. It seems that Gensim calculate the results very fast. Although when I want to calculate the most similar, my function is extremely slow:

```
def euclidean_most_similars (model, word, topn = 10):
      distances = {}
      vec1 = model[word]
      for item in model.wv.vocab:
        if item!= node:
          vec2 = model[item]
          dist = np.linalg.norm(vec1 - vec2)
          distances[(node, item)] = dist
      sorted_distances = sorted(distances.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

I would like to know how Gensim manages to calculate the most nearest words so fast and what is an efficient way to calculate the most similar words.

Comment: How fast or slow is it now? How fast do you need it to be? How fast does the competitor Gensim perform on the same data? Without numbers, it's all premature optimization.

Comment: I tested my function and Gensim's most_similar function. Gensim shows the results instantly, although my function takes almost 10 seconds

Comment: Would you mind providing a minimal, complete example for us to run?